# mysql prevent update other salve-master db while any record update in slave db

Tags: mysql, replication

I have master and 3 slave (slave1,salve2,slave3) db in same host. So when I update any record in slave1 db its affected on all other master and salves db.

My Question is: **How to prevent update all other db whenever I update any record in salve1 db, and whenever I update any record in master it will be updated in all db?**

in short I want to replicate db in one way master to salve not slave to master..

Comment: You should not update in a slave. And even if you did, the changes would not reach the master. Only sub-slaves of that slave.

Comment: @ypercube sub-slave also update master record

Comment: I don't think this can ever happen in mysql (or any master-slave) replication. Please update your question with details of your setup (settings of master, slave1, ..., which instance is slave of which, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume you have the following databases:

```
Master  (DB0); 
Slave 1 (DB1); 
Slave 2 (DB2); 
Slave 3 (DB3);
```

The only way for a 'slave' (e.g DB1) to update the 'master' (DB0) is if the 'slave1' (DB1) is also acting as a master to the 'master' (DB0). (commonly known as `Master to Master` Replication)

You can check if this is the case by connecting to your 'master' (DB0) database and running `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`

The result 'should' be blank, most likely it isn't.

Look for the fields:
`Master_Host` and `Master_Port` - this is the database from which it is receiving data. It will probably relate to one of your 'slaves' (DB1).

`Slave_IO_running` and `Slave_sQL_running` - if these are both 'Yes' then replication is up and running, and any changes made to the database above will appear on your 'master'

The quickest way to stop it is to then issue `STOP SLAVE;` on your 'master' (DB0).

Depending on what version of MySQL you are running there are then some things you can do to erase the settings. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reset-slave.html (I recomend making a note of the settings in `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` before issuing any kind of RESET, just in case)

Also you may want to add:
`skip-slave-start` to your my.cnf file on your master, which will prevent the database starting replication again if the server is restarted.

As @ypercube mentions above, you should avoid writing to a 'slave' database, unless you have specifically configured it as part of a master to master setup.